# Demand for jQuery or jQuery UI freelancers?

Tags: consulting, project

I have the following experience:

- Four years experience in PHP, MySQL and WordPress
- Proficiency in jQuery and jQuery UI

Is there demand for freelancers with experience in jQuery and jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on freelancing websites like oDesk and elance (now UpWork) for 10 years.

I am a PHP developer, and I have seen jQuery projects with equivalent and higher wages quite often.

For every say 5 PHP programmers there is 1 programmer who knows both PHP and jQuery **well** and is obviously paid higher.

jQuery UI work is much more elegant and easy to use. It is definitely in.